# Idea for a chart from dataset with 9 variables?

Tags: excel, visualization, chemistry, originlab

I have some challenges in writing my thesis. I have an experimental dataset with 9 variables in a table. I'm exploring options for creating a meaningful chart from this data. Variables V4 represent volume (except for the last 9 rows, which represent mass); V5 is for mass; V6 is for the ratio; V7 is the number of cycles, and V8 is measured in minutes. Higher values in V7 and V8 indicate longer experiment durations.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBcIq.jpg)

I am thinking of creating a yes/no-type chart, that visualize the main result if it did work or not. but how to put the other variables, makes me quite struggle

Comment: I have no idea what kind of experiment you have done. But looking at your data, it seems that you do not need a visualization. You can summarize it in a few sentences (which experiment set has worked, which failed).